# SQL syntax error, when saving date to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I Use simple sql query to save some date to database.

mysql column:

```
current_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
```

But when executed query show Error:

```
insert into
  computers
  (computer_name, current_date, ip_address, user_id)
values
  ('Default_22', '2012-01-01', null, 37);
```

[2016-03-22 12:21:46] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_date, ip_address, user_id)

Comment: `current_date` is reserve word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_date` is a [mysql function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), you can't have it as columns alias in your insert into query;

try escaping your column names

`` insert into computers (`computer_name`, `current_date`, .... ``

Answer (score 0):

"current_date" is reserved in MySQL, so use (`) character to enclose field names

Use this

```
INSERT INTO computers
  (`computer_name`, `current_date`, `ip_address`, `user_id`)
VALUES
  ('Default_22', '2012-01-01', null, 37);
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_date` is a mysql reserved keyword, try: `select current_date`, you can either rename your columns, or escape your query like this:

```
insert into
  computers
  (`computer_name`, `current_date`, `ip_address`, `user_id`)
values
  ('Default_22', '2012-01-01', null, 37);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the mysql documentation
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date

`current_date` is a function in MySQL, which returns the current date.
So either change the column name or escape the column name in the insert into with backticks.

```
insert into
  computers
  (`computer_name`, `current_date`, `ip_address`, `user_id`)
values
  ('Default_22', '2012-01-01', null, 37);
```

Comment: you should not use simple quotes for column names: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/379105)

Comment: its should be \``  not ''

Comment: Thanks i changed it.